# Returning index of non-zero elements in each row if their count exceeds a threshold

Tags: python, numpy

I have a truth array of the form:

```
truth_arr = array([[ True, False, False,  True],
                   [False,  True, False, False],
                   [False, False,  True,  True],
                   [False, False, False,  True]])
```

and I want to get the indices of all true items where there is more than one true in a row. The above array should return something like:

```
 [(0, 0), (0, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

(not necessarily in that form).

Comment: I don't get it, what is wrong with this question? It's definitely note off-topic, not asking for debugging, and based on the answers below, it has enough details to explain the problem. I don't thing a MWE is needed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mask rows that do not meet the criteria, then use `np.nonzero`:

```
np.nonzero(truth_arr * truth_arr.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)>1)
# (array([0, 0, 2, 2]), array([0, 3, 2, 3]))
```

If you really want a list of tuples format for your indices, use `np.column_stack` after:

```
np.column_stack(
    np.nonzero(truth_arr * truth_arr.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)>1))
# array([[0, 0],
#        [0, 3],
#        [2, 2],
#        [2, 3]])
```

Or, more pythonically,

```
[*zip(*np.nonzero(truth_arr * truth_arr.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)>1))]
# [(0, 0), (0, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

a slight variation of [@cs95's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56754678/5052365), just to get the output in the form suggested in the question:

```py
import numpy as np

truth_arr = np.array([[True, False, False, True],
                      [False, True, False, False],
                      [False, False, True, True],
                      [False, False, False, True]])

indices = np.nonzero(truth_arr * truth_arr.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True) > 1)
result = list(zip(*indices))
print(result)
```

Output:

> [(0, 0), (0, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3)]

**NOTE:**

the original answer's output is how `numpy` likes these indices, so you can use:
`truth_arr[indices]` to get `[ True  True  True  True]`,

whereas `truth_arr[result]` will cause an error...